# Mass Port Forwarding?

Tags: ubuntu, networking, ftp, port-forwarding

Hi I had trouble but I finally port forwarded 21-23 and thus got SSH working on my Ubuntu machine.

If I want to do other things with it such as FTP, should I just port forward 1-10000 so I don't have to worry about port forwarding each individual port? What are the advantages/disadvantages of this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest thing to do is to put the machine in the router's **DMZ**, but this (and your plan as well) will expose your system directly to the Internet at large, thereby vastly increasing your security risk. The best thing to do is to expose services only as needed.

Also, ssh is only port 22. You can close 23, but 21 will handle FTP as long as the client uses passive mode.